# button inside updatepanel causes unwanted full postback

Tags: ajax, updatepanel, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm making lost password recovery on my login page and I'm doing it with ModalPopUpExtender, a Panel and two of those inside of an UpdatePanel. But somehow when clicking the "btnOkPassRequest" full postback happens. People had similiar problems with other controls, some that UpdatePanel obviously didn't encapsulate. But never with a Button. What am I missing?

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager><asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>  
    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
    <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server"TargetControlID="HyperLink2" BackgroundCssClass="ModalPopupBG" PopupControlID="pnlPopupPass" CancelControlID="btnCancelPassRequest" OkControlID="Button1"></cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlPopupPass" runat="server" CssClass="ModalPopup">   
      <div class="ModalHeader">Password recovery</div>
      <div class="ModalBody">
        <p>Please, enter username.....</p>
        <table>
        <tr>
                <td>Username</td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="tbModalUserName" runat="server" class="textbox"></asp:TextBox></td>            
            </tr>
          </table>
        <table>
            <tr>
          <td></td>
            <td><asp:Button ID="btnOKPassRequest" runat="server" Text="Request new password" CssClass="button-wide" onclick="btnOKPassRequest_Click" PostBackUrl="~/Login.aspx" /></td>
            <td><asp:Button ID="btnCancelPassRequest" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CssClass="button-wide"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>        
      </div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    </asp:Panel>
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnOKPassRequest" EventName="btnOKPassRequest_Click" />
</Triggers>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem dissapeared when I switched to ajaxcontroltoolkit v1, instead of using 3.5, which is really confusing

Comment: you should verify which version of .NET your app is running in.  The toolkit currently has a version for 3.5 and 4.0, which can target framework-specific functionality that may not exist in both frameworks.
I believe when it first came out it was for 2.0, if you installed the AJAX add-ons.  These AJAX libraries and controls were integrated into .NET in the .NET Framework version 3.5.

Answer (score 2):

I think EventName should just be "Click" not "btnOKPassRequest_Click" in the trigger

Comment: fixed. It was there as an attempt of despair. Se also comment at Nick Clarke's. Any other idea? Thanx

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure this should be there?

```
 PostBackUrl="~/Login.aspx"
```

As without this it works fine for me.

I also removed the trigger, but if you need the trigger then the EventName should be Click.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlPopupPass" runat="server" CssClass="ModalPopup">
                <div class="ModalHeader">
                    Password recovery</div>
                <div class="ModalBody">
                    <p>
                        Please, enter username.....</p>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Username
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="tbModalUserName" runat="server" class="textbox"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Button ID="btnOKPassRequest" runat="server" Text="Request new password" CssClass="button-wide"
                                    OnClick="btnOKPassRequest_Click" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Button ID="btnCancelPassRequest" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CssClass="button-wide" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
            </asp:Panel>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: I have this  PostBackUrl="~/Login.aspx" there because there are other controls on the page that post back to other URL.
I found a problem at the form tag also, that I thaught was causing my problems (and I had need for PostBackUrl="~/Login.aspx to override it):

<form id="Form1" method="POST" runat="server" action="/EFormsASP/Default.aspx">

But when I removed action="..." it still isn't ok. Any other idea?

Comment: As long as you want the UpdatePanel to postback to the same url as the form/page the PostBackUrl is not required.

Are the other controls outside of the UpdatePanel in your example?

Comment: I know UpdatePanels don't play nice with all controls, so I did a search and found this:

http://blogs.technet.com/kirtid/archive/2007/05/03/using-updatepanels-with-modalpopups.aspx

Maybe it helps.